# python error going from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

I have a python script that takes in a command-line argument a directory that has data, i,e. `python3 test.py /data/`

I wrote it in Jupyter on a Windows machine. I test the script in a windows terminal and everything works great. I need it to run on an Ubuntu machine. I downloaded Ubuntu LiveCD just to test it. I get into an Ubuntu terminal in the folder where the script and the data are located. I enter this exact line:

```
python3 test.py /data/
```

and I get a syntax error on line 91 which has

```
image = plt.imread(directory_name + "image-" + f"{i:02d}" + ".jpg")
```

The arrow points to the second " in the f"{i:02d}". I also try entering

```
python3 test.py
```

without the directory and I get the same exact error. What's weird is I wrote try/except to store the directory to a variable and throw an exception if it's formatted wrong. Again, it works in Windows just fine. Here is the code for the try/except:

```
#import directory location of images, catch exceptions
import sys

try:
    directory_name = sys.argv[1]
    print(directory_name)

except:
    print('Please pass directory_name')
```

Note that it's not printing the directory name in Ubuntu. I assume I get the error because Windows's directory syntax is different than Ubuntu's (which I am not too familiar with). How can I fix it?

Here what I see with the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwRJj.png)

The code is as described above. The first thing in the script is the try/except, then several custom functions, and then the line that gives me the error.

Comment: Can you share full stack trace and your code ?

Comment: A syntax error isn't related to libraries or platform-specific paths. It's an error in your code. f-strings were introduced [in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498). You're probably using an older version of Python if it's an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: That's exactly right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the install library  on Ubuntu. It is not preinstalled in the system and you use.

```
import mathplotlib as plt

image = plt.imread(directory_name + "image-" + f"{i:02d}" + ".jpg")
```

Comment: I installed matplotlib and the other packages, already had import mathplotlib as plt, but still getting the same error.